# MySQL multiple join based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I have 3 tables..
say.

1. users`(id,name,role_id(FK to roles)`
2. staff `(id,name,user_id(FK to users)`
3. role `(id,name)`
4. students `(id,name,user_id(FK to users)`

i need result like: 
  when a user is a student(roleid=5) i need to join with student table and fetch student details. or when a user is staff(role_id=3) then i need to fetch details only from staff table and display. How can it possible.
i have written a query which left join with 2 tables but it show other table which are not participate in this case.

here i am share what i come across

```
    select * 
      from users u 
     JOIN roles r on u.role_id=r.id 
left join staff st on st.user_id=u.id 
left join students s on s.user_id=u.id 
    where u.id=11068
```

`role_id=3:staff` and `role_id=5 student` is something like switch case in C programing

What i looking for is that

```
switch(role_id){ case 3: JOIN with students table;return;case 5:JOIN with staff table;return;}
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: i believe that the question is clear to all

Comment: If there will only be a match on staff or student, then use COALESCE in the SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use those role_id's in the joins for the staff & students.

Since either the staff name or the student name will be empty you can use a COALESCE to get only 1 name.

```
select 
 u.name as user_name, 
 u.role_id,
 r.name as role_name,
 COALESCE(sta.name, stu.name) AS name
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
LEFT JOIN staff sta ON (sta.user_id = u.id AND u.role_id = 3)
LEFT JOIN students stu ON (stu.user_id = u.id AND u.role_id = 5)
WHERE u.id = 11068
```

But I don't think it's needed with those extra rules in the joins.

I assume you could say someone is a student if they are in "students".
And a staff when they are in "staff".
Regardless of the role_id.

And in SQL you can use a CASE also as a switch.

```
select 
 u.name as user_name, 
 u.role_id,
 r.name as role_name,
 (CASE u.role_id
  WHEN 3 THEN sta.name
  WHEN 5 THEN stu.name
  END) AS name
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
LEFT JOIN staff sta ON sta.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN students stu ON stu.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 11068
```

Comment: it is working but shows student_name=NULL as like in my query

Comment: can a user be both a student and a staff?  Or maybe it has a different role_id than 3 or 5?

Comment: no..here one user either be student or staff. yes there other roles rather that this 3 and 5

Comment: If you run the second query, what role_id does that user have?

Comment: his roleid is 3 and it return the result but it also shows student name which is not needed for this

Comment: How would you call that name field then which can be either a staff or a student. "other_name" ?

Comment: is it possible for checking roleid first and find it which is the user and return relevent data. as incase of SWITCH in C Language

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186650/discussion-between-sreejith-sreeji-and-lukstorms).

Comment: The second query now uses a CASE, which can be used in 2 ways.

Comment: Thanks second query is what i wanted

Comment: About the 2 ways to use a case, look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html